# How to send a UDP Packet with Web RTC - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, udp, webrtc

How do you send a UDP Packet using Web RTC?

Comment: Hey user, I'm working on WebRTC and would love to help, but you have to provide more details; otherwise, this will be closed as not a real question. Can you show an example of what you're trying to do? WebRTC really doesn't use UDP, it uses TCP over WebSockets (or WebSockets over TCP). Hence, without further clarification, I'm really not sure this makes sense.

Comment: Sure, here's something similar using ICE: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics

But i'm looking for something simpler. Like a chat example.

Thanks

Comment: Okay, well, I'm not sure you understand the purpose of Stack Overflow. It's really not intended to write code for people, but to instead solve real, actual, specific problems they're facing. What you have here is still pretty vague. What is it that you're trying to do? I suggest you [edit] your post to include lots more detail about the problem. There are examples of WebRTC out there already, so if you're doing something different than that, please explain what that is. Good luck! :)

Comment: http://apprtc.appspot.com << Load in 2 different Chrome WebRTC-enabled browsers...

Comment: I stand corrected! WebRTC uses UDP for the RTP portion of the data transfer. You can see this by doing a TCPdump. However, the SIP messaging is done over WebSockets, and that's all TCP. As spicyramen said, check out sipml5. Hope this helps!

Comment: here's another example: http://simpl.info/dc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check sipml5, http://code.google.com/p/sipml5/
get the code and look into the folder:
sipml5/src/tinySIP/src/transports

Answer (score 24):

You can't send a UDP packet directly with WebRTC.  That would violate the basic security constraints required by the browser.

You can send [SRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Real-time_Transport_Protocol) to an [ICE-enabled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment) host.  That is probably not what you are looking for.

If a browser permitted sending arbitrary UDP packets, then malicious applications could send packets to any host.

This might not sound so bad, after all, hosts on the Internet need to be able to deal with that right?  The problem is that some browsers are in protected environments where access to the network is restricted.  Within those networks, some hosts are far less protected than a host on the public Internet might be.  This would be OK, since access to the network is controlled.

If it were possible for a browser to send arbitrary packets, a user on a browser in that environment could be convinced to send specifically crafted packets to one of these poorly protected hosts.  Likely, that would result in the network operator banning the browser, which is something browser-makers want very much to avoid.

WebRTC only sends certain types of UDP packet under specific conditions.  If the host that you are interested in talking to understands [ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment) and is able to consume [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) with [SRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Real-time_Transport_Protocol) or [SCTP over DTLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-tuexen-tsvwg-sctp-dtls-encaps) (unlikely methinks).  Then perhaps you could force the browser to send something.

Comment: You don't make a distinction between arbitrary payload and arbitrary destination address. If the browser implements the same security constraints as it does for TCP, but more strictly (for instance, limiting the destination IP address to the host the script was loaded from), this wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

> @Martin Thomson has explained the problem very well. By taking
> motivation from his post, this post might provide guidance to some
> geeks and newbies.

It is being said that WebRtc is `Real-time`, `Bi-directional`, `Secure` communication between two or more peers. I will more focus on the word: **Secure**.

---

Security policies of enterprise networks typically require filtering of incoming *unsolicited traffic*, *blocking certain protocols*, and doing *application-level filtering* and *scanning* for `spam`, `malware`, and `intellectual property`.

**Now two new questions come to mind;**

> 1. Why is TCP traversal not problematic?
> 2. Why is UDP traversal problematic?

---

**Why is TCP traversal not problematic?**

TCP clearly indicates two things;

- The beginning of a flow `(SYN)` and,
- The end of a flow `(FIN or RST)`.

This is used by firewalls to `open` and `close` **pinholes**. Exceptionally, a TCP connection that has received no traffic for a long time also has its pinhole closed (to accommodate network topology changes or failure of both TCP peers). Firewalls also perform protocol validation to clean up problems with

- Out-of-window TCP segments and,
- Overlapping TCP segments

> This allows the firewall to protect the network and protect hosts from
> several attack vectors (replay attacks, host IP address probing, DDOS
> attack, etc.).

---

**Why is UDP traversal problematic?**

For UDP flows, the first outgoing packet on a 5-tuple will be used by the firewall as a `start-of-session` indicator. But UDP does not have an `end-of-session` indicator, so the firewall has only `two ways` to close a pinhole:

- Timing out the pinhole after the `interior host` does not send traffic
  for several seconds or
- The interior host generates a fatal `ICMP error`.

Because there is no reliable way to determine that a session is being stopped, the firewall has a much harder job. It could implement an Application-level Gateway `(ALG)` and be aware of whatever semantics are imposed by the higher-level code on top of UDP.

It could also rely on a set of well-known application servers to inform it of sessions as they start and end, but that suffers from many challenges as application servers are hosted independently of the network on which they are used.

> Using an `ALG`, a firewall can determine when the call is terminated and
> close any dynamic mappings created for the media session. But the
> problem is session signaling between the WebRTC application running in
> the browser and the Web server that could be using TLS, in which case
> the ALG no longer has access to the signaling.

---

**Conclusion:**

So, at the Application-Level Gateway, Webrtc utilizes a combination of `SDP` and `ICE`. WebRtc basically wraps `UDP` in such a way that

1. For Audio, Video Channels, WebRtc uses combinations of `RTP`, `RTCP`, `SRTP` over `DTLS`.
2. For Data Channels, webrtc uses the Stream Control Transmission Protocol `(SCTP)`, defined in [RFC 2960](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2960).

> SCTP is a transport layer protocol that was intended as an alternative
> to `TCP` or `UDP`. For WebRtc, we use it as an application layer
> protocol that runs over our DTLS connection.

These protocols also come with some new protocols such as `STUN`, `TURN`. For the basic implementations of WebRtc Please follow;

- [WebRtc Experiments by Mauz Khan](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment)
- [WebRtc Experiments by Muhammad Usman Bashir](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC)

I hope this explanation might help some of the geeks. Thanks