# Why can not I open a UDP connection on the client side (in browser)?

Tags: javascript, websocket, udp, dart, online-game

I know that there WebSockets. I looked at it from itself is an example of language dart.

```
void initWebSocket([int retrySeconds = 2]) {
  var reconnectScheduled = false;

  outputMsg("Connecting to websocket");
  ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');

  void scheduleReconnect() {
    if (!reconnectScheduled) {
      new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 1000 * retrySeconds), () => initWebSocket(retrySeconds * 2));
    }
    reconnectScheduled = true;
  }

  ws.onOpen.listen((e) {
    outputMsg('Connected');
    ws.send('Hello from Dart!');
  });...
```

That is nothing but the creation of new connections and work with it already.
That is a separate thread (in fact, in which runs javaScript) connection is established and so on.
Why then dart and JavaScript I can not in the same thread to open a simple UDP connection and work with him?

P.s.UDP is more preferred for online-browser-realtime-games.

Comment: Maybe WebRTC suites your needs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading from udp port in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605252/reading-from-udp-port-in-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browsers don't support it due to security constraints.
You should take a look at [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/)

see also

- [How to send a UDP Packet with Web RTC - Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216785)
- [Can I use WebRTC to open a UDP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811854)