# Make a direct udp connection in javascript / HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, udp, webrtc

Is it possible in javascript/HTML5 (no node.js) to make a direct bilateral connection to an UDP server ? There's WebRTC but from want I understand you can't send datagram to a specific server.

My main concern is to make a game that communicates with his server over UDP, so I know the server's address, no need of ICE or such things like that...

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You cannot in native javascript open direct UDP/TCP ports. It is designed this way for [security purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605252/reading-from-udp-port-in-browser).

You will have to put in a breaker between your frontend and the destination server(I would say websockets to udp). So, have a websocket server in C(possibly with [libwebsockets](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets)) to communicate to your web app and then translate the data and push it over `UDP`

There are breakers that already exist for specific purposes Check out [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216785/how-to-send-a-udp-packet-with-web-rtc-javascript)

Comment: I'm making the client and the server so it wouldn't be a problem about websocket communication. The problem would be the "delay" (introduced by TCP over UDP) between the client and the server during the gameplay... 
In any case, I will use this technique and see what happens ... Thank you !