# Can't use core nodejs module with browserify (dgram)

Tags: node.js, browserify

**node -v** => v5.5.0

**commande** => "watchify src/js/app.js --extension=.jsx -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react stage-0 ] ] -o public/js/bundle.js -dv",

**versions:**
"browserify": "^12.0.1",
"watchify": "^3.6.1"

**error console**
app.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Dgram.createSocket is not a function

**my code in app.js :**

```
var PORT = 33333;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var Dgram = require('dgram');
var message = new Buffer('My KungFu is not good :(');

var client = Dgram.createSocket('udp4');
client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('UDP message sent to ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
   client.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dgram` cannot be used client-side with browserify.

Only a subset of node's core modules are supported by browserify:

> Get browser versions of the node core libraries events, stream, path, url, assert, buffer, util, querystring, http, vm, and crypto when you require() them

[source](http://browserify.org/).

Have also a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17619908/1006854) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29537902/1006854) regarding UDP's unavailability inside the browser.

Comment: okay thanks. Now, I found how to make an alias or something else.