# Send UDP packet with Angular2

Tags: angular, udp

I want to send UDP packets with an Angular 2 app. Is this possible?

If not is there a way to send TCP packets? 
I read that `socket.io` only works with other `socket.io`s.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to talk to UDP sockets with HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532157/how-to-talk-to-udp-sockets-with-html5)

Comment: @user2699453 Did you found a solution?

Comment: Sadly not. I switched to mqtt