# Is it possible to implement a UDP socket in Rust for the WebAssembly (WASM) and use it in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, rust, udp, webassembly

I am currently working on implementing a UDP socket in Rust for a WebAssembly (WASM) environment within a web browser. I've tried to create the UDP socket using the provided Rust code, but I'm encountering issues, and I'm in need of some guidance.

The specific problem I'm facing is that when I attempt to run the Rust code within the Browser environment, it's not working as expected. I'm encountering an error that I'm unable to resolve on my own.

Build the project using: `wasm-pack build --target web`

The error message I'm receiving in the browser console is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__wbindgen_add_to_stack_pointer')
at new UdpSocketClient (udp_socket_wasm.js:162:18)
at Socket.js:6:38
```

Sources below:

src/lib.rs:

```rs
use std::net::UdpSocket;
use std::str;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsValue;
//use web_sys::{console, window};

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct UdpSocketClient {
    socket: UdpSocket
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl UdpSocketClient {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Result<UdpSocketClient, JsValue> {
        let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:0").map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&e.to_string()))?;
        Ok(UdpSocketClient { socket })
    }

    pub fn send(&self, host: &str, port: u32, data: &[u8]) -> Result<(), JsValue> {
        let server_address = format!("{}:{}", host, port);
        self.socket
            .send_to(data, &server_address)
            .map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&e.to_string()))?;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn receive(&self, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, JsValue> {
        self.socket
            .recv(buffer)
            .map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&e.to_string()))
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[package]
name = "udp_socket_wasm"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2"
web-sys = "0.3"
js-sys = "0.3"
```

Socket.js:

```js
import { UdpSocketClient } from './pkg/udp_socket_wasm.js';

const udpSocket = new UdpSocketClient();

// Send UDP data
const host = '127.0.0.1'; // Replace with your host
const port = 6900; // Replace with your port
// const data = new Uint8Array([/* your data here */]);

const textMessage = "Hello, UDP!"; // Your message as a string
const textEncoder = new TextEncoder(); // Create a TextEncoder

// Encode the message as a Uint8Array
const data = textEncoder.encode(textMessage);

udpSocket
    .send(host, port, data)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Data sent successfully.');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sending data:', error);
    });

// Receive UDP data (this is asynchronous)
const buffer = new Uint8Array(1024); // Adjust the buffer size as needed

udpSocket
    .receive(buffer)
    .then((bytesReceived) => {
        console.log(`Received ${bytesReceived} bytes:`, buffer.slice(0, bytesReceived));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error receiving data:', error);
    });
```

index.html (header tag):

```html
<script src="Socket.js" type="module" defer></script>
```

I attempted to reinstall wasm-bindgen-cli and wasm-pack, but these actions did not resolve the issue.

I also experimented with window.onload to ensure that it wasn't executing before the source was fully ready, but it appears that this wasn't the root cause of the problem.

The desired result:
I am attempting to implement UDP socket support in a web browser to establish communication with my backend service, which also relies on UDP for data transmission.

Comment: UDP sockets are not available in the browser. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532157/how-to-talk-to-udp-sockets-with-html5

Comment: A browser that lets WASM code create random sockets would be a gigantic security vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the information about security.I was interested, because the legacy service I'm trying to connect to is only supporting UDP. Looks like I'm going to have to make WebSocket proxy service or something else.