# How to send M-SEARCH from Javascript / Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, udp, upnp, ssdp

Is it possible to send a [SSDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) [M-SEARCH](http://buildingskb.schneider-electric.com/view.php?AID=15197) from javascript in a browser? The protocol is based on UDP, and the message I'd like to send from Javascript should look like this:

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
MAN: "ssdp:discover"
MX: seconds to delay response
ST: search target
USER-AGENT: OS/version UPnP/1.1 product/version
```

Someone asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216785/how-to-send-a-udp-packet-with-web-rtc-javascript), more generically about sending UDP packets from a browser. The answer doesn't actually show any code samples however.

I realize [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) allows for things like [DataChannels](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/), but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm literally looking for a way to send UDP packets from javascript running in a browser, like the example above.

Answer (score 3):

Sending SSDP `M-SEARCH` from browser is impossible.

Only UDP supported is not necessary for SSDP, because SSDP is multicast packet, so joining multicast group is also required.

As far as I know, only Chrome apps(with special permission) can do joining multicast group.