# How to send a UDP package in browser using HTML5 or WEBRTC?

Tags: html, browser, udp, webrtc

I want to send an UDP package to my UDP server in browser. I heard that HTML5 or WEBRTC can do something, but I don't know how.

Can someone help me?

Comment: are you talking about sending message using [RTCDataChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel)?

Comment: as long as i can send a udp(i know the data format) to my udp server using browser,thats OK

Comment: Or is it a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216785/how-to-send-a-udp-packet-with-web-rtc-javascript/13478490 ?

Answer (score 3):

You could either write a chrome extension (app) which would give you access to https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp (`"sockets": {...}` in your manifest.json).

Or, as far as WebRTC goes:

```
var pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(
    { "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:localhost:1234" }] }
);

pc.createOffer(function (sessionDescription) {
    pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);

}, function(error) {
    alert(error);
}, { 'mandatory': { 'OfferToReceiveAudio': true, 'OfferToReceiveVideo': true } });
```

You'd then able to get the UDP packets on localhost:1234 via:

```
$port = 1234

t = Thread.start do
  server = UDPSocket.open
  server.bind(nil, $port)
  a = server.recvfrom(12364)
  puts server.send "ping", 0, a[1][2], a[1][1]
end
t.join
```

Comment: I know the data format,How can i send my data,for example ,my data is [0x80,0x01,0x11].

Comment: I'd look into building a chrome extension then: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp#method-send.

Comment: Apparently UDP sockets are not possible in extensions anymore. It was possible at one point, but they disabled it due to security concerns -- restricting it only to Chrome apps, which are being ended/phased-out now as well. :/

Comment: I was able to get some packages using this `webkitRTCPeerConnection` API, but they seem to be encrypted or something. How do I actually parse it / read it? Also, how do I send my data, like some text for example?