# What's the point of having UDP in node.js if browsers can't send/receive UDP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp

It's great that Node.js has the dgram package that enables UDP communication.

[But web browsers can't send UDP packets](https://gafferongames.com/post/why_cant_i_send_udp_packets_from_a_browser/) to a server. Web browsers also [can't read UDP packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605252/reading-from-udp-port-in-browser) from a server. The only way to use UDP in a web browser is to [use webrtc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216785/how-to-send-a-udp-packet-with-web-rtc-javascript).

So it seems like the only way to really use Node.js+UDP is through purely server side code, communicating from one .js file to another.

It seems like there is no "networking" really going on here, since it's all the data is staying on the server and not being sent to clients. I may as well use an observer or something.

So what's the point of having UDP in Node if I can't send/receive UDP packets in the browser?

Comment: Browsers are not the only possible software clients out there.

Comment: You answered your own question.  Node is used for more than just server to browser.  For example, some folks have written DNS servers in Node.js.  DNS is a UDP based protocol.

Comment: Node.js is a general purpose JavaScript implementation, it's not only for writing webserver.

Comment: I see, I suppose I was thinking too narrowly with just server <--> browser communication!